# document.getElementById(id) and toggling multiple ids

Tags: javascript, toggle, getelementbyid

I have this simple function which toggles a hidden element in the webpage.

```
function showtable(id) 
 {
 if(document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'block')
  {
document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
  }else{
document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
}
 } 


<input type="button" value="Toggle" onclick="showtable('id');" />
```

This works fine, but I want to toggle off some other (table) element (with certain ids) (except for the one which is being toggled, whether on or off) on the page every time the button is clicked.

Comment: The goal is unachievable, because “every other element” includes the `body` element, and setting `display: none` hides its all descendants too (including your button). Please clarify. Explaining why you are doing this might help, too.

Comment: Sorry for being dubious. I edited my question. I need to hide some other table elements which is already visible because it does not look good if if two table element is visible at the same time. I want to make only one table element is visible at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use jQuery, but if you don't want to use that; here is a pure javascript example. To see how it works, copy paste it in a text file, save it as test.htm and open it in a browser. It contains three tables, each with a button above it. When clicking a button, it's table gets displayed and all other tables get hidden. If you need more tables, give them an id, and add their id to the array in the function:

```
var ids = ["redTable", "greenTable", "blackTable", "anotherTable"];
```

If you want to be able to toggle that table also, it will off course also need a button:

```
<input type="button" value="Toggle Green Table" onclick="showtable('anotherTable');" />
```

example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function showtable(id) {
                var ids = ["redTable", "greenTable", "blackTable"];
                for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                    if(ids[i] != id)
                        document.getElementById(ids[i]).style.display = "none";
                }
                document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Toggle Red Table" onclick="showtable('redTable');" /><br />
        <table style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;" id="redTable">
            <tr>
                <td>redTable</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="button" value="Toggle Green Table" onclick="showtable('greenTable');" /><br />
        <table style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: green; display: none;" id="greenTable">
            <tr>
                <td>greenTable</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="button" value="Toggle Black Table" onclick="showtable('blackTable');" /><br />
        <table style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: black; display: none;" id="blackTable">
            <tr>
                <td>blackTable</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could select all the other DOM elements, set their display attribute to "none", and then only show the one that should be visible.

Another way would be to keep track of the visible element in a variable:

```
var visibleElement = null;
```

When you toggle an element, you make that one the visible element and hide the previously visible one:

```
// Hide the previously visible element, if any.
if (visibleElement != null)
{
    visibleElement.style.display = 'none';
}

// Make your new element the visible one.
visibleElement = document.getElementById(id)
visibleElement.style.display = 'block';
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy using [jQuery](http://jquery.com). For example, give each toggled element a class like `toggle_element` and then in JS:

```
$('.toggle_element').hide();
$('#id').show();
```

This will hide all elements with class `toggle_element` and show element with id `id`.

JSFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uxRfR/).

Comment: Why do you provide jQuery solution to a question where OP is clearly using raw JavaScript?

Comment: @Tadeck - because the OP is doing something that can be easily achieved using jQuery and I dare say he is unaware of this

Comment: This is very simple task and since OP seemingly is not using jQuery, I would not propose him to add whole JavaScript framework solely to perform this action. Take a look at the accepted answer, to see that it is easily achievable in pure JavaScript also. Anyway you have given good alternative for people who already use jQuery.

Comment: I will give raw JS first next time, Thank you for the response :)